# работа с csv python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Как сделать чтобы было так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а не так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду очень благодарен!

код

```
import csv

with open('nomer_email.csv', mode = 'w', newline = "") as csv_file:
    nomers = ['8 888 888 8888', '9 999 999 9999']
    emails = ['sasha_123@mail.ru', 'dima_321@gmail.com']

    dict_nomer_emails = {
    "list_nomers": nomers,
    "list_emails": emails
    }

    fieldnames = ["phone_numbers", "emails"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames = fieldnames, delimiter = "\t")

    writer.writeheader()

    for key, values in dict_nomer_emails.items():

        if key == "list_nomers":
            for value in values:
                writer.writerow({"phone_numbers": value})
        if key == "list_emails":
            for value in values:
                writer.writerow({"emails": value})
```

Comment: Используйте лучше библиотеку `Pandas`, всё будет гораздо проще типа `df = pd.DataFrame('list_nomers': nomers, 'list_emails': emails)` и записать в файл будет очень просто.

Comment: CrazyElf, мне бы через стандартную библиотеку сделать

Comment: "@CrazyElf" not CrazyElf

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить такое решение:

```
import csv

with open('nomer_email.csv', mode = 'w', newline = "") as csv_file:
    nomers = ['8 888 888 8888', '9 999 999 9999']
    emails = ['sasha_123@mail.ru', 'dima_321@gmail.com']

    fieldnames = ["phone_numbers", "emails"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames = fieldnames, delimiter = "\t")

    writer.writeheader()

    for row in zip(nomers, emails):
        writer.writerow({k: v for k,v in zip(fieldnames,row)})
```

Выходной файл:

```
phone_numbers   emails
8 888 888 8888  sasha_123@mail.ru
9 999 999 9999  dima_321@gmail.com
```

Наверное, можно сделать ещё проще как-то, но я библиотеку csv почти не знаю, предпочитаю работать с Pandas.